# mysqli_ error on attempted connection close

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to empty mysqli query after calling a procedure. Here is my code:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) 
{
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
echo"blockSeparate";
$_POST['address']='Str';
if($clientIntercome=$mysqli->prepare("CALL mbusGetClientIntercomeByAddress(?)"))
{
    $clientIntercome->bind_param("s",$_POST['address']);
    $clientIntercome->execute();
    $clientIntercome->bind_result($id,$flat,$phone,$redirectPhone);
    while($clientIntercome->fetch())
    {
        echo"".$id." ".$flat." ".$phone." ".$redirectPhone."\n";
    }
}
else
{
    echo"SMTH is wrong";
}
$clientIntercome->close();
while(true)
{
    echo"WORKS";
    $mysqli->store_result();
    if (!$mysqli->more_results())
    {
        break;
    }
    if (!$mysqli->next_result())
    {
        break;
    }           
}
echo"blockSeparate";
if($clientKeys=$mysqli->prepare("CALL mbusGetClientKeys(?)"))
{
    echo"Here works too";
    $clientKeys->bind_param('i',1);
    $clientKeys->execute();
    $clientKeys->bind_result($rf_id,$phone);
    while($clientKeys->fetch())
    {
        echo"".$rf_id." ".$phone."\n";
    }
    //$clientKeys->close();
}
else
{
    echo$mysqli->error;
}
$mysqli->close();
```

I init `$_POST['address']` to test this script on server, usually I use it via ajax.

```
var address=$("#cfgAddress").val();
var data={address:address};
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: "./getUserFlatPhone.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        console.log(data);
//some work
    }
});
```

If I try it with uncommented strng it returns PHP internal server error, however if it is commented there is not mistake, but next query returns commans out of sync mistake. However this code (while loop to empty mysqli procedure call) works fine at my app. Also if I run it in browser not via jquery it returns no mistake, but don't post results.
**EDIT:** changed commented string that fails my work

Comment: what does your code have to do with your title?

Comment: It parses results of mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Exceptions to get exact error/issue.
2. Use Close() to end the mysqli connection only.

Try this:  http://pastebin.com/SsYHsALL

Answer (score 0):

This line is not a `mysqli` connection. So don't us `close()` on it. Delete it instead.

```
$clientIntercome->close();
```

This line in [the correct way to close the connection per the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php):

```
$mysqli->close();
```